# Prove that $(\alpha, \beta)^T$ is a point on a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, circles, solution-verification

Let M be a collection of points $M=\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\2 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 2\\2 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}$.

The points on a circle with radius r and center in $(a,b)^T\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is described by the equation
$(X-a)^2+(Y-b)^2=r^2$

which is equivalent with the equation

$2aX+2bY+(r^2-a^2-b^2)=X^2+Y^2$

Now let $v=\begin{pmatrix} 2a\\2b \\r^2-a^2-b^2 \end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^3$

Show that $(\alpha,\beta)^T$ is a point on the circle described above if and only if

$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta & 1 \end{pmatrix}\cdot v=\alpha^2+\beta^2$.

Solution: I assume that $(\alpha, \beta)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is a point on the circle $(X-a)^2 + (Y-b)^2 = r^2$ and want to show that this implies $
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot v = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 
$. As $(\alpha, \beta)^T$ is a point on the circle is a solution to the equation $2aX+2bY + (r^2-a^2-b^2) = X^2 + Y^2$. We calculate and have that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot v 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
2a \\
2b \\
r^2-a^2-b^2
\end{pmatrix}
 = 2a\alpha + 2b\beta + \left(r^2-a^2-b^2 \right) = \alpha^2 + \beta^2
 $$
Can you verify if this way is correct? I think it is. The other way I am a little bit unsure about. I read another post with the same question and they said to use that $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = \alpha \cdot \alpha + \beta \cdot \beta = |\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = |\alpha + \beta|^2 = \langle \alpha + \beta, \alpha + \beta \rangle$ by using the Pythagores and and the fact that the dot product of is the square of the norm. But how do I go from here?

My own solution, without using the above, were to assume that $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta & 1 \end{pmatrix}\cdot v=\alpha^2+\beta^2$ is met and want to show that this implies that $(\alpha, \beta)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is a point on the circle $(X-a)^2 + (Y-b)^2 = r^2$. But as the first is  met can I just use this to say that $(\alpha, \beta)^T$ must be a point on the circle $(X-a)^2 + (Y-b)^2 = r^2$. But by doing this have I just assumed what I want to show?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3628239/265466. You two appear to be taking the same course.